# FindById gives me "code": "MODEL_NOT_FOUND" - loopback 3

Tags: find, loopback

I have been facing this weird issue lately that on a given model when I try to fetch an item by Id it throws an error even though this item exists in the db.

```
{   "error": {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "name": "Error",
    "message": "Unknown \"BidSample\" id \"5afc396af6584c07cf1b729c\".",
    "code": "MODEL_NOT_FOUND"   } }
```

I am using mongo database and loopback 3.

Comment: Please provide url that use in request.

Comment: Use /BidSamples/ instead of /BidSample/.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that in the database it has been soft deleted.

Comment: You should add some reference to what `soft delete` means.